# PHP Freezing (again)

Tags: php, email

My website has a create account form, in which it inserts into a database and sends an email and verifies on my AWS SES server. But for some reason my code keeps freezing. If I put an `echo "Testing"` right above `//include_phpmailer`, "Testing" will not show up.

```
<?php

//include phpmailer
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('ses.php');

$username = "scapXXXXXX";
$password = "baXXXXXXXX";
$hostname = "db4free.net:3306/scapterlogin";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Could Not establish connection!" . mysql_error());

$dbselect = mysql_select_db("scapterlogin", $dbhandle);

$myusername = $_POST['user'];
$mypassword = $_POST['pass'];
$myemail = $_POST['email'];

$query = "INSERT INTO userInfo (Username, Password, Email, activation_code) VALUES('$myusername',             '$mypassword', '$myemail')";

$myquery = mysql_query($query);

if ($myquery) {
//verify email address using SES
$verify = new SimpleEmailService("access_key", "secret_key");
$verify->verifyEmailAddress($myemail));


//SMTP Settings
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host       = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
$mail->Username   = "AKIAXXXXXXXXX";
$mail->Password   = "AoDRf8NBXXXXXXXXXXX";
//

$mail->SetFrom('webmaster@scapter.org', 'The Scapter Team'); //from (verified email address)
$mail->Subject = "New Account"; //subject

//message

$body = 'Dear " . $myusername . ", \r\n Welcome to Scapter! We hope you enjoy all of our products. We         have got an account request from this email.
If you did not create an account, you can safely ignore this email.';
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
//

//recipient
$mail->AddAddress($myemail, $myusername);

//Success
if ($mail->Send()) {
//setcookie('loggedin', $myusername, Time()+3600);
//header('Location: login.php');
}

//Error
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    //echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Jumping to the conclusion that your code is "freezing" is not very constructive. Why do you think this? Have you considered other causes for the symptoms you've seen?

Comment: It could be your database or SMTP. I doubt it is is your code (At Least the code you just posted).

Comment: Use `die();` as well instead of just `echo`. You will know which line is really the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of unusual factors in your code..

1. $hostname for db connection does not seem to be a valid one (db4free.net:3306/scapterlogin). If you have an IP address of the db server, you should use that instead.
2. Using 
   if ($mail->Send()) {}
   and
   if(!$mail->Send()) {}
   effectively calls the same method twice you should replace 2nd occurrence with a simple else condition.

Using 'die' before $mail->Send() or $myquery = mysql_query($query); can help you identify whether the specific block of code is causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You say if you echo on the first line, it will not show up, which leads me to believe that the file is not being loaded, and maybe you have error display turned off, so it's not giving you an error? Check your logs for errors - maybe you are not loading this file with the correct name or you have permissions set so that your server doesn't want to run it.